# How can I apply a parent group's layer styles to child layers when using 'Generate Image Assets' in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, layer-style

I have a group in Photoshop containing many layers, which I'm exporting as individual assets using the 'File > Generate > Image Assets' tool. The parent group has a layer style for styles that should be shared across all these layers. When the image assets are generated, these layer styles are not applied.

Is there any way to get Photoshop to use the group's layer styles when exporting the child assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get Photoshop to use the group's layer styles when exporting the child assets?

In short - no. But you can transfer them to your individual layers without too much trouble.

What you need to do is right-click on your group within the Layers Panel and choose 'Copy Layer Style'... You'll want to Clear Layer Style from the Group as well so that your effects are not applied in duplicate.

Then highlight all desired layers within the group, right-click and choose 'Paste Layer Style'. Now (properly named) individual assets will be generated with Layer Styles.

Comment: Oh, it didn't even occur to me that you could paste layer styles to more than a single layer at a time. Kind of a shame since this solution wouldn't work if I also needed individual layer styles on each layer that would get overridden by the group's pasted layer styles. This does work in my particular case though. Thank you!

Comment: @Bryson Thill ... You're welcome. Glad I could help